# TransformXml with new csproj format?

Tags: .net, transformation, csproj

I've recently upgraded a solution from using the old xml format of the csproj files to the new that came after xproj was deprecated.
i.e. the format which looks something like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>
    <AssemblyName>MyProject</AssemblyName>
    <PackageId>MyProject</PackageId>
    <GenerateAssemblyConfigurationAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyConfigurationAttribute>
    <GenerateAssemblyCompanyAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyCompanyAttribute>
    <GenerateAssemblyProductAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyProductAttribute>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

The problem is that this solution contains alot of xml transformation which have stopped working. 
These transformation are initiated by the MyProject.wpp.targets file as I've understood it. I haven't set this up myself and I don't have that much knowledge about it but since this file is of the same format as the old csproj files I'm guessing it might be a reason why it's not working but I don't know. 
Any help is greatly appreachiated on how to get this working again.

This is how the wpp.target file looks like today

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <Import Project="[MSBuild]\CommonConfigTransforms.xml"/>
    <Import Project="[MSBuild]\BuildSpecificConfigTransforms.xml"/>
    <Import Project="[MSBuild]\DeleteTempConfigFiles.xml"/>

    <PropertyGroup>
        <PrepareForBuildDependsOn>
            $(PrepareForBuildDependsOn);
            CommonConfigTransforms;
            BuildSpecificConfigTransforms;
        </PrepareForBuildDependsOn>
        <BuildDependsOn>
            $(BuildDependsOn);
            DeleteTempConfigFiles
        </BuildDependsOn>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [Migrating tasks from old csproj to new csproj format #2746](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/2746) GitHub issue of the MSBuild repository:

> You have to change Target to be suitable with new approach (in this situation **AfterTargets="PrepareForBuild"**) so the new part of csproj should looks like this:

```
<UsingTask TaskName="TransformXml" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll" />
<Target Name="ApplyConfigurationConfigFile" AfterTargets="PrepareForBuild" Condition="Exists('App.$(Configuration).config')">
  <ItemGroup>
    <AppConfigWithTargetPath Remove="App.config" />
    <AppConfigWithTargetPath Include="$(IntermediateOutputPath)$(TargetFileName).config">
      <TargetPath>$(TargetFileName).config</TargetPath>
    </AppConfigWithTargetPath>
  </ItemGroup>
  <TransformXml Source="App.config" Destination="$(IntermediateOutputPath)$(TargetFileName).config" Transform="App.$(Configuration).config" />
</Target>
```

Comment: Great, thank you for this. I've added this target to `Directory.Build.targets` at the solution level, so it "just works" for any projects having transformation files by convention.

Answer (score 2):

A few years later, it's now even easier to perform App.config transforms thanks to the [Microsoft.VisualStudio.SlowCheetah](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.VisualStudio.SlowCheetah/) NuGet package. Here's how to modify your csproj to enable transformations: add the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.SlowCheetah` package and update your App.config original and configuration-specific files metadata with `TransformOnBuild` and respectively `IsTransformFile`.

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.SlowCheetah" Version="4.0.8" PrivateAssets="all" />
  <None Update="App.config">
    <TransformOnBuild>true</TransformOnBuild>
  </None>
  <None Update="App.*.config">
    <DependentUpon>App.config</DependentUpon>
    <IsTransformFile>true</IsTransformFile>
  </None>
</ItemGroup>
```